# Make a reusable ui-bootstrap uib-dropdown directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have several Angular UI-Bootstrap drop downs in directives like so... I have identical ones for Manufacturers,and Districts, etc.. The only difference being the $state.go destination and the Service used to get the data.  It seems like there has got to be a better way to do this... any ideas?

```
/* Distributors DDL Directive  */
(function (angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('ddlDistributors', [])
    .directive('ddlDistributors', ['$state', 'DistributorsService',
        function ($state, DistributorsService) {
            return {
                bindToController: {
                    distributors: '='
                },
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                scope: true,
                controller: function () {
                    var vm = this;
                    vm.distributors = DistributorsService.query();
                    vm.showDistricts = function (id, distributorname) {
                        console.log("clicked on distributorid: " + id);
                        $state.go('map.distributordistricts', { distributorid: id, distributorname: distributorname });
                    }
                },
                templateUrl: 'templates/ddl.distributors.html'
            }
        }
    ]);
})(window.angular)
```

And here is the template...

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
<button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" dropdown-text-set>
    Select Distributor <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="distributor in vm.distributors"><a ng-click="vm.showDistricts(distributor.Id, distributor.Name)">{{distributor.Name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```